# Can I improve this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, context

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4166566/what-shapes-can-be-involved-in-equal-area-tilings-of-finite-polygons) question of mine was closed as I need to "provide additional context".  I'm struggling to think of what context exactly I could add - there is no external motivation of the question apart from "I was thinking about tilings and the question occured to me, and I couldn't solve it", and all of my progress on the matter is covered in the comments.  Is the issue that I haven't made enough progress on the problem on my own, or that the problem lacks any external motivation or implication, and therefore could not be improved because there isn't a larger context for it?

Comment: I recognize that the sentence "Is the issue that I haven't made enough progress on the problem on my own" might come off as hostile/defensive, but I couldn't think of a better way to phrase it.

Comment: I think that it is best not to focus on making "an attempt" at solving the problem.  Rather it would be better to explain anyone should care about that problem. Where does it come from (provide a complete reference)?  Why are you interested in solving the problem?  What theorems or definitions might apply?  For further advice, please see [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @TheZachMan You wrote "... all of my progress on the matter is covered in the comments". This should be in your question text.  Note the first edit after a question is closed will put it into the reopen queue where members may possibly vote to reopen it. Since this is the only time it'll automatically be put into that queue, please try to make sure your edit is sufficient to likely get your question reopened. I've read your comments and, although they'll help, I'm not sure if they're enough. Thus, please first read Xander's link & add to your edit anything more it suggests which might help.

Comment: I suppose the issue is that I don't really have any of those - there is no reference for the problem because I came up with it myself, I'm only interested in solving the problem because it doesn't seem to have an obvious solution - there is no extrinsic motivating question, and there's not any material I'm familiar with that's relevant (though it seems plausible that looking further into the term "isoperimetric" mentioned in the Answer could turn some up).

Comment: sometimes people do not bother to  read comments when voting to close, so you should put whatever you can add as context in the question body (and what you have I think is sufficient)

Comment: Hm, well I've encountered a new problem - in thinking about how to edit the post to be acceptable, I've stumbled upon a solution - which of course I can't post, given that the question is still closed.

Comment: @TheZachMan you shouldn't be posting an answer at this stage: you should edit your question to include your thoughts on a solution (and incorporate useful information from the comments, as mentioned above by other commentors).  The aim is to get a good question *and* answer, not a good answer to a poorly presented question.

Comment: Are you sure your solution is correct? If yes, then it's not important if your post is reopened or not. If you are not sure of the solution, do post your thought in the post, pointing out where you have problem with. I guess that would be sufficient contexts.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I think that your comment puts the onus in the wrong place.  Rather, people should not *have* to read the comments in order to understand the question.  It is not that they "don't bother"---the fundamentally should not have to do so.  Comments are meant to be ephemeral, and are not meant to contain any information which is key to understanding the problem.  One should vote on a question based on the question itself, and not the attached comments.

Comment: @XanderHenderson thank you, it was not at all my intention to have this meaning